# Defining division using Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, user-defined-functions, integer-arithmetic

I decided it would be cool to learn Haskell by recreating arithmetic using only the Succ function, or other functions I've defined, and the Integer number type. So far I've managed to (re)create Add, Subtract, and Multiply, only for Integers. I've created a predecessor function as well.

However, I want division over rational numbers, but I don't want to borrow anymore types. What I'd like to do is use a pair of Integers to define the numerator and denominator and work from there. What's cool is that if I figure this out, the complex plane and operations on it should be a similar.

(I know that using the Integer type is technically cheating, and that I don't need it. But if I do fancy things like Peano arithmetic (?) I also have to figure out how get the system to represent the solution with pretty digits and the like. )

How would I define a custom "rational" number type as a pair of two Integers?

Comment: Probably not as trivial as you would've thought: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm

Comment: Have you checked out Data.Ratio http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/libraries/haskell2010-1.1.1.0/Data-Ratio.html ?

Comment: Once you have division with remainders worked out, you can get your pretty digits.

Comment: Do you really want the rationals (that are pairs with where you *equalize* pairs `(n,m) == (q,r) <=> n*r = m*q` or just division with remainder (that's just repeated subtraction if you really want  to keep it simple)?

Comment: Carsten, your comment made me think. You're right, I can already implement integer div and mod. And I've already started thinking that division is not trivial (i.e. Mephy). But my goal here is to get a taste of Haskell and functional programing, and "reinvent" arithmetic from the most bare bones set of tools I can. I'll need rationals!

Comment: Ok - do you know the mathematical backgrounds for this kind of stuff? It's not really that hard (really just the think I mentioned above if you check for equals, and similar stuff for <, ...) - or you go with @גלעדברקן and check this package

Comment: If you are looking for some bonus fun that will really get you thinking in a more functional way, you could try working with [church encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) instead. The natural numbers can be represented as a function that takes a function, and composes it with itself that many times. For example `five f = f.f.f.f.f`. Then, if you want to actually extract a number out, you just say `five succ 0`. Addition? `add f g = f g`. Multiplication? `mul f g = f (add g)`. Building up both data and computation out of nothing but functions can be quite entertaining.

Comment: Carsten: I don't have the required math, I'm just an engineer who had a CS and a Math major as roommates once and have an amateur interest in CS. But I got this far in a few hours work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go about it like so, the traditional inductive way:

```
data N = Z | S N deriving (Show, Eq)
cmp Z Z = EQ -- of course, could have derived Ord
cmp Z _ = LT
cmp (S _) Z = GT
cmp (S x) (S y) = cmp x y

add Z x = x
add (S x) y = S $ add x y

sub Z x = Z -- have to do something to negative numbers
sub x Z = x
sub (S x) (S y) = sub x y

divi x y | cmp x y == LT = (x, Z)
divi x y = fmap S $ divi (sub x y) y -- dividing by Z will not terminate
```

Then we have

```
Prelude> divi (S $ S $ S Z) (S $ S Z)  -- 3 / 2 == (1,1)
(S Z,S Z)
Prelude> divi (S $ S $ S $ S Z) (S $ S Z)  -- 4 / 2 == (0, 2)
(Z,S (S Z))
```

Answer (score 0):

for some background on how to encode integer arithmetic in rewriting
(and you can easily translate this into first-order functional programs), see

Walters and Zantema, Rewrite Systems for Integer Arithmetic,
http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-1994/1994-43.pdf

Contejean, Marche, Rabehasaina, Rewrite Systems for natural, integer, and rational Arithmetic,
https://www.lri.fr/~marche/articles/rta97.ps.gz

and references cited there.